# Walking Through Nested For statements

Tags: python, nested

I'm supposed to take a look at this model solution in order to work on my next assignment for a class. This program returns ASCII values between 32 and 126 inclusive. I'm understanding it until the "for statements". Could somebody please help me walk through it? I know that it has to do with creating the four columns, but I think it would be beneficial to understand every bit of it before moving on.

Thanks so much.

```
START = 32

END = 126


def GiveAscii(start=START, end=END, width=4):

    """Returns an ascii chart as a string. Readable."""

    entries = end - start +1
    entries_per_column = entries/width
    if entries % width:
        entries_per_column += 1
    ret = []
    for row in range(entries_per_column):
        for column in range(width):
            entry = entries_per_column * column + row + start
            if entry > end:
                break
            ret += ["%3d = %-6s" % (entry, chr(entry))]
        ret += ['\n']
    return ''.join(ret)

def main():
    print GiveAscii()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `end` shouldn't be used for a variable name. It's a keyword.

Comment: As far as practical advice goes, why don't you try adding this statement after your second `for` loop? `print "R:", row, "C:", column`

Comment: @2rs2ts `end` is not a python keyword.

Comment: @Yossi it's not? whoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one enumerates the range from zero to the value of `entries_per_column` as a variable named `row`

For each row, there is an enumeration from zero to the value of `width` as a variable named `column`

So this is creating a two dimensional matrix - should be pretty digestible.

For each `column` in a `row`, the value in that space is assigned to the variable `entry`. If the `entry` does not exceed the maximum value of the matrix, then it is put inside the return list `ret` as a list. After this `ret` is given a newline character so that a new row can be created visually (when `ret` is printed out). So this program makes a list, `ret`, which contains a two dimensional matrix of values - a number of lists that are `row`s, each of which contain some single-valued lists called `column`s, which have `entries` inside of them.

I hope this is clear!

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks! The only place where I am still confused is the equation for "entry". This: "entry = entries_per_column * column + row + start". I don't know why, but I'm having trouble understanding the logic of that equation...

Comment: @user2376566 That assignment is generating iterative values for the matrix cells. If you use an IDE like PyCharm (there's a free trial! http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), you can set a breakpoint at this statement and walk through it step by step, seeing what happens every time you go through the loop. That should definitely help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to comment your code to see if it could help you

```
START = 32

END = 126

# A function to return a string which represents an asci grid
def GiveAscii(start=START, end=END, width=4):

    """Returns an ascii chart as a string. Readable."""
    # The number of entries is the end minus the start plus one
    entries = end - start +1
    # Doing an integer devide provides us with the floor of the entries per column
    entries_per_column = entries/width
    # If our division was not even
    if entries % width:
        # We need to add an extra entry per column
        entries_per_column += 1
    # Initialize our array
    ret = []
    # For every row
    for row in range(entries_per_column):
        # Go through every column
        for column in range(width):
            # Do this math to create this entry, multiply first!
            entry = entries_per_column * column + row + start
            # If the entry is larger than the value end
            if entry > end:
                # Leave this column
                break
            # Not really sure what this formatting is but it is a formatting statment
            # Char casts your number as a character
            ret += ["%3d = %-6s" % (entry, chr(entry))]
         # When we are done with our column print and endline charachter
         ret += ['\n']
    # Return your array
    return ''.join(ret)

def main():
    print GiveAscii()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm following everything, but the math "entry = entries_per_column * column + row + start". Could you explain why this equation is here please? Thanks!